# Angularjs animation on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, animation

I have an ng-repeat setup and working with filtering. When I apply a filter I would like to simply fade out all currently displayed elements and then fade back in the filtered set. All the demos I've seen will fadeOut just the elements that are being filtered out at the same time fading in the filtered elements. I would preferably see a demo using JS animation.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/fbQFfTHN2qsi6gygpShz?p=info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
 <li class="page-list-item" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <span>{{ item }}</span>
    </li>
```

CSS:

```
.page-list-item.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -moz-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -ms-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -o-transition:0.2s linear all;
    transition:0.2s linear all;

    -ms-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}


.page-list-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    -ms-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}

.page-list-item.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -moz-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -ms-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -o-transition:0.2s linear all;
    transition:0.2s linear all;

    -ms-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}

.page-list-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    -ms-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you but not exactly... see here with your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/fbQFfTHN2qsi6gygpShz
If you type "Z" into the filter, I would like all elements including Zebra to fade out, so for a quick moment there is nothing displayed, and then Zebra would fadeIn. I would also like to see this with JS animation rather than CSS.

Comment: I like many thing about Angular but it annoys me when I can't find an answer to something that should be so simple.